# Reset/reformat FileVault-protected machine without login password, macOS Catalina

Tags: filevault

I received a FileVault-protected MacBook running macOS Catalina and do not know the administrator login password.  How do I perform a factory reset or otherwise prepare the laptop for a new user?

An authorized Apple repair shop told me I was out of luck and that I'd been given a brick.

Comment: If an AASP told you that you have a brick, chances are you have a brick, sorry to tell you. That is not to say that the machine cannot be "un-bricked" however, but this is not supported by any means and is quite involved. (Unless you can prove ownership to the AASP, in which case they should be able to do it for you using supported toolkits in AST2) More info is needed. What model MacBook do you have? (either the A-number or serial, if you're comfortable with posting it online) When you turn the machine on, what screen does it boot to?

Comment: @kumowoon1025 I'm asking on behalf of my former employer. In the main question above, you can interpret "I" as "They". They're trying to refresh my laptop for a new user. I assume they have receipts to show proof of purchase. I don't have access to the machine. It's a relatively new MacBook Pro.

Comment: "Unless you can prove ownership to the AASP, in which case they should be able to do it for you using supported toolkits in AST2" Does it apply to Apple Silicon MacBooks: can AASP actually "un-brick" the system using AST2? AppleCare tells me that AST2 isn't able to reset admin password if no MacBook-specific admin credentials are provided; full system reset is only possible via http://al-support.apple.com (with proof of ownership), not at AASP.

Answer (score 4):

I encountered this same problem and have been able to solve it.  Filevault was used to lock the laptop.  Previous employee left and we didn't have the password.  When we tried recovery mode it still required a password, as did internet recovery mode.

The hint is in one of the other answers on here, which is that 'apple support says internet recovery doesn't require the login password'.  This is actually true, it's just not readily apparent what to do after starting in internet recovery mode because the first screen you see is still the login screen.  However if you click 'recovery assistant' on the top left, you'll see an option for 'erase mac' which will essentially erase the contents of the laptop allowing you to reinstall the macOS.

After erasing, the computer will restart and you'll see the the typical blinking folder with a question mark (because all the startup files were deleted), but you just follow the regular recovery process again (recovery mode by restarting and holding cmd+r) and you can reinstall the factory setting macOS.

I've run into other issues since restarting such as recovery images not unmounting properly so I'll probably need to use a bootable USB, but at least the HD is wiped and finally unlocked!

Comment: Thanks. This is indeed what did the trick for me. The 'Erase mac' option is very easy to miss as it's hidden away.

Comment: I didn't initially realize that "Internet Recovery Mode" is different than regular Recovery Mode. `option+command+r` gets you Internet Recovery Mode.

https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/use-macos-recovery-on-an-intel-based-mac-mchl338cf9a8/14.0/mac/14.0#mchl69906860

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out! 
That "Choose Account" screen is so dominant that I never thought to look in the menu.

Answer (score 2):

Firmware password is something you need the password or Apple’s willing assistance to bypass.

FileVault and data encryption is trivial to erase by booting to another OS (Internet Recovery is often the easiest other OS) to wipe and reinstall.

Firmware password and hardware failures are the only things that interfere with an erase and install in my experience, once you have reviewed a couple support articles.

Here are the relevant references and definitions:

- https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204455 Firmware
- https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201314 Recovery
- https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT208496 Erase
- https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT208987 Activation Lock

Note, if you erase a Mac, you still may be faced with an Activation Lock or a [device management MDM under Apple School Manager or Apple Business Manager](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT209617).

Answer (score 0):

Apple customer service stated that macOS Recovery over the Internet does not require the login password, and that someone could erase/reformat the drive using that tool.  https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201314

Comment: Wait, you were able to solve your problem by booting into internet recovery??

Comment: Are you sure the repair shop you went to was "authorized"? I can't help but question their competency if they told you the machine was bricked, it sounds like it wasn't even locked, just encrypted.

Comment: No, it was locked. I was told this method did not work after all, despite Apple's assertion.

The repair shop insinuated that a non-authorized shop might be able to fix the machine despite the lock/encryption, but that they weren't allowed to use such techniques.

Comment: Ah, I see. Yeah, then it likely has a firmware passcode or iCloud lock set on it, so to an authorized repair shop, it is supposed to be a brick. (Since it may have been locked remotely after being stolen, etc.) It sounds like it is company property though, so as you say, proving ownership would be possible. Proof of purchase from an authorized reseller would be sufficient for original owners, and the AASP should reset the firmware password for you. The encryption is a different story, but since you're trying to wipe the device clean anyway, that shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: They sent me a screenshot saying they were ultimately blocked by an iCloud login screen, despite the fact I removed the device from my account (via the apple.com website). Sounds like it needs either the Apple Store or an AASP willing to bypass the login to wipe the device.

Ironically, I think I might have been able to wipe the device remotely if they hadn't asked me to remove it from my iCloud account.

Comment: Well, you would have been able to wipe the data on the device, that's for sure. But the lock would have stayed in place. The remote wipe is not something you do to "clean slate" your device. Its intended function is to destroy the possibly sensitive data so it does not fall into the wrong hands. It is pretty much only used when you've misplaced your device with sensitive data, or had it stolen, so the lock stays in place, the theory is, if stealing an Apple device gets you a brick 90% of the time, crooks won't steal them as much.