Resetting Mac to factory setting - Override Admin username and password
When my old job closed shop, I was given my old Mac laptop to keep. It is running Catalina. I like to reset it to factory setting but it requires administrator log in info which I do not have. Is there any way I can override administrator log in? I tried to turn off FileVault but that also requires admin username and password.

I think these two links will answer your questions: 1, 2.

The answer here may help https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/392513/reset-reformat-filevault-protected-machine-without-login-password-macos-catalin. You will lose all your files on the Mac so make a copy of important stuff elsewhere. This may not work depending on how much your Mac has been locked down. Apple will only assist if you have documented proof of ownership (which I suspect you don't have).

You allude to the fact you need an account with Admin privileges to do what you want.  Is it safe to say that your user account is not an Admin?  Do you know if the Mac was enrolled in some sort of MDM program?
